# Navigator and Provider conflict in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

sending data between screen using Provider with Navigator concept make a conflict

error after the run

The following ProviderNotFoundError was thrown building SecondRoute(dirty):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this SecondRoute Widget

To fix, please:

- Ensure the Provider is an ancestor to this SecondRoute Widget
- Provide types to Provider
- Provide types to Consumer
- Provide types to Provider.of()
- Always use package imports. Ex: `import 'package:my_app/my_code.dart';
- Ensure the correct `context` is being used.

https://www.ideone.com/xHXK5m

Answer (score 0):

you can pass data like this put data in class

```
RaisedButton(
child: Text(‘Send data to the second page’),
onPressed: () {
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => SecondPage(
       data: data,
    )),
 );
 }, 
 ),
```

and recieve data like this

```
class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
final Data data;
SecondPage({this.data});
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(‘Constructor — second page’),
  ),
  body: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 54.0,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: Text(‘Data passed to this page:’,
           style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700))),
        Text(‘Text: ${data.text}’),
        Text(‘Counter: ${data.counter}’),
        Text(‘Date: ${data.dateTime}’),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  );
  }
```

Comment: i can use constructor but i want to use Provider

Answer (score 0):

You can try placing whatever `Provider` value you have above the `MaterialApp` and thus the navigation or, when you push to a second page, provide the value again. Providers are scoped to widget trees, so this is expected behavior.

As an example, to pass a value to another route, you could do something like

```dart
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
    final foo = 'foo';

    Provider<String>.value(
      value: foo,
      child: NewPage(),
    );
  }));
},
```

And then just consume it like regular in the NewPage route.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
MaterialApp(
title: 'Navigation Basics',
home: ChangeNotifierProvider(
  builder: (context) => Data(),
  child: FirstRoute(),
))
```

Delete `ChangeNotifierProvider` in `FirstRoute`